# Sitecore.Data.Query.ParseException: 'End of string expected at position 36.'

Tags: sitecore8.1

What is the problem with the format.

This is working fine:

```
/sitecore/content/Test/Healthy Living/*[@@templateid='{8297A5DB-42B1-434F-9A2F-85DF7BC57E24}']
```

But this one not:

```
/sitecore/content/Test/Aging and Wellness/*[@@templateid='{8297A5DB-42B1-434F-9A2F-85DF7BC57E24}']
```

I'm getting the next issue

> Sitecore.Data.Query.ParseException: 'End of string expected at
>   position 36.'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because of `and` word in your query.

You need to escape your query with `#` characters like that:

```
/sitecore/content/Test/#Aging and Wellness#/*[@@templateid='{8297A5DB-42B1-434F-9A2F-85DF7BC57E24}']
```

More to read here: [Escape characters / words in a Sitecore query](http://www.newguid.net/sitecore/2012/escape-characterswords-in-a-sitecore-query/)